# Pygame how do I display a variable?

Tags: python, variables, text, pygame

I am making a game in which you click on a coin and get coins, and I am trying to display the amount of coins you get, but it isn't displayed.

the code:

```
text = basicFont.render(str(coins), True, WHITE, BLACK)
textRect = text.get_rect()
textRect.centerx = windowSurface.get_rect().centerx
textRect.centery = windowSurface.get_rect().centery
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use something similar to this:

```
score = 0
score_font = pygame.font.Font(None, 50)
score_surf = score_font.render(str(score), 1, (0, 0, 0))
score_pos = [10, 10]
```

`score` here is the variable, which can be changed via functions in the class(es). `score_font` will determine the font and size the text will be in. `score_surf` will be used to render the text onto the surface. It will need the variable with the necessary string, the number 1 (I not quite sure why), and the color in which the text will be. `score_pos` will be used to blit the text onto the specific coordinates given. Here is how you blit the text onto the screen:

```
screen.blit(score_surf, score_pos)
```

I hope this helps you!

Answer (score 1):

Once you make your object, draw it into your screen with `windowSurface.blit(text, (x1, y1)`. Then call `pygame.display.flip()` to show it.

As in:

```
import pygame, sys
from pygame.locals import *

pygame.init()
windowSurface = pygame.display.set_mode()

myfont = pygame.font.SysFont("monospace", 15)

while True
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == QUIT:
            pygame.quit()
            sys.exit()
    # render text
    label = myfont.render("Some text!", 1, (255,255,0))
    windowSurface.blit(label, (100, 100))
    pygame.display.flip()
```

Comment: Your answer did not work. I used the following code:                                # set up the text
    text = basicFont.render(str(coins), True, WHITE, BLACK)
    textRect = text.get_rect()
    textRect.centerx = 240
    textRect.centery = 240
    windowSurface.blit(text, (x1, y1)

    pygame.display.flip()                                                                                   It said it had invalid syntax.

Comment: @AnonymousPerson please post full traceback in your question as an edit.

Comment: When I ran it, it said "Invalid syntax", and pygame in pygame.display.flip was in red.